# How to play audio from url in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

This is my code

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:recentActivity.url];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
 [audioPlayer play];
```

and it's not playing audio

Comment: i have tried this, but not working.

Comment: did you try with different urls

Comment: yes sir, i use, "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3"

Comment: But sir,
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:recentActivity.url]; //Add any link of audio file which you want to play
                playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recentActivity.url]]; // add url to playerItem
                
                player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]; // add player item to AVAudioPlayer
                player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
                [player play];

Using this its works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.** It will work fine.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];    
self.avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];    
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];    
self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];    
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

**For Swift 3.0**

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer!
var slider: UISlider!

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
    var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound", ofType: ".mp3")!)
    var error: Error?
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    }
    catch let error {
    }
    if player == nil {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    player.prepareToPlay()
    slider.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)
    slider.value = 0.0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    player.play()
}

func updateTime(_ timer: Timer) {
    slider.value = Float(player.currentTime)
}

@IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
    player.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
}
```

Comment: i have uislider, and my my song in runnning but when i click on slider then i want to change the time of playing accroding to slider click. how i can set ?

Comment: @HarimohanAgrawal check update answer but it's in swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this small piece of code to play audio from an URL

Create a new helper calls and add the following code to  `PlayerHelper.h`

```
    @interface PlayerHelper : NSObject
{
    AVPlayer *player;
}

+ (PlayerHelper*)shared;

- (BOOL)playAudio:(NSString*)urlPath;

- (void)stopPlayer;

- (void)pausePlayer;

- (void)seekTo:(float)time;

- (float)duration;
@end
```

Add following code to `PlayerHelper.m` file

```
 #import "PlayerHelper.h"

@implementation PlayerHelper
+ (PlayerHelper*)shared{
    static PlayerHelper *helper = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        helper = [[PlayerHelper alloc] init];
    });
    return helper;
}

- (void)stopPlayer{
    if (player != nil) {
        player = nil;
    }
}

- (void)pausePlayer{
    [player pause];
}

- (BOOL)playAudio:(NSString*)urlPath{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (player == nil){
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    }
    if (error == nil) {
        [player play];
        return TRUE;
    }
    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    return FALSE;
}

- (void)seekTo:(float)time{
    [player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(time, 1)];
}

- (float)duration{
    return player.currentTime.value;
    return 0;
}
@end
```

Usage,

```
NSString *url = @"https://isongs/media/rapon.mp3";
[[PlayerHelper shared] playAudio:url];
```

Comment: but i have used Uislider, and i want to also, play,pause, show timing continiously etc. so how can i manager UISlider.

Comment: or any third party which have all thing, please let me know.

Comment: @HarimohanAgrawal check it, I have updated with seek functionality

Comment: I have used you code, but audio not play.

Comment: in this line
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:&error];


player is nil.

Comment: and it return false.

Comment: in error

Printing description of error:
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"

Comment: @HarimohanAgrawal which means your audio URL is not a valid one, can you share me URL I will check

Comment: "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3"

Comment: https is also added, but not show on stackoverflow.

Comment: i have also check my url on google, and when i used

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:recentActivity.url]; //Add any link of audio file which you want to play
                playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recentActivity.url]]; // add url to playerItem

                player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]; // add player item to AVAudioPlayer
                player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
                [player play];


the song is play. but for seek bar i asking the functionality.

Comment: updated, if you want to implement slider functionality, use seekTo method. i hope this will helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code (assuming that you're using ARC) is that you're allocating `AVAudioPlayer` and then you send `play` message but as soon as your method returns the ARC deallocates the `AVAudioPlayer` and hence you won't be able to listen any sound. To resolve this issue please retain your `AVAudioPlayer` instance either in an `ivar` or in some property. Below is the example of an `ivar`

```
@implementation ViewController {
  AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3"];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil]; // Now we are assigning it in an instance variable thus ARC will not deallocate it.
  [audioPlayer play];
}


@end
```